# Prevent mysql_result($sql_result, 0) throwing an error

Tags: php, mysql

If there are no results for $sql_result, it throws an error...
What is the correct method to do this to prevent an error if there are no rows.. It cant be that you have to count the rows before?

```
mysql_result($sql_result, 0);
```

Kind regards to any responders.. J

Comment: Easiest way to stop `mysql_result` from throwing an error is to *stop using it*.  It's ancient, and barely maintained anymore.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (is_resource($sql_result)) {
    $value = mysql_result($sql_result, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to test `$sql_result` first.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($sql_result !== false             # query was successful
 && mysql_num_rows($sql_result) > 0)  # query returned rows
{
    // do your thing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the approach I prefer:

```
$sql = "SELECT * ....";
$r = mysql_query($sql);
if (!$r) throw new Exception('Error: ' . mysql_error() . '; Attempted: ' . $sql);
if (mysql_num_rows($r) > 0) {
   //Process Result
} else {
   //Deal with an empty Result Set
}
```

I throw an exception if the mysql query fails because, in my applications at least, a failed sql query is a deal breaker: continuing normal script execution isn't going to accomplish anything useful~ [There's an error with the SQL syntax or a DB connection issue]. The Exception bubbles up until the Application has somewhere appropriate to catch such an issue.

I use an application specific Exception: `ExceptionMySQL`, so that I can intelligently catch it higher up in the application: e.g.

```
//Top Level Application
try {
   //Execute appropriate application call
} catch (ExceptionMySQL $e) {
   //Deal with a mysql exception
} catch (ExceptionPermission $e) {
  //Deal with a permission Exception
} catch (//etc. etc. etc.
```

Comment: Not a bad idea, although you'd definitely want to pick a type more specific than `Exception` to throw... :)  And if you're not already using exceptions, note that this will cause your script to die if the query was unsuccessful.  Often that's the right thing to do in this case, but it's still something to be aware of.

Comment: @cHao Yeah, I was going to use the Exception that I actually use, but I was concerned it was make my answer less clear =)

Comment: This approach seems to add a lot more work and logic to a single query than is necessary and clean.  PHP throws and error if the query is bad...but not if there are no rows.  PHP will also throw an error if the query is good, the resultset is empty, and you go right toward acting as if there IS a row, but the standard procedure to 1) check if (is_resource($result)) then 2) while ($row = mysql_query($result)) allows you to accommodate empty result sets without cumbersome Exceptions and in just plain if/then/else.  Why complicate things?

Comment: @hexparrot You don't appear to understand my code. It throws an exception only if the returned value from `mysql_query` is falsey (i.e. not a resource). From my experience, the most common logical fork after querying is "Is the result set empty?", so I included it in my example.

Comment: @hexparrot: Consider that you can break the "do the query and throw an exception if it failed" part off into its own function.  At that point, when you call your new `query` function, if it returns at all, the query was definitely successful.  End results being, among other things, you don't have to check each query to see if it succeeded, and you won't have PHP errors spitting out for non-fatal stuff.